# vue formulate doesn't update the vuex state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar, vue-formulate

hope you are all good
currently, I'm working on quasar project, I am stuck on forms, I googled a npm package and found formulate, I did everything the docs said.

made this file

```js
// boot/formulate.js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueFormulate from "@braid/vue-formulate";

Vue.use(VueFormulate);
```

included this file to my boot section in quasar.config.js

```js
// quasar.config.js
boot: ["i18n", "axios", "formulate.js"],
```

added this file to store modules like this

```js
// store/modules/formulate.js
import { formulateModule } from "vue-formulate";
export default formulateModule("namespace");
```

and included it to the store

```js
// store/index.js
const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      //....
      // other modules
      formulate
    },

    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode only
    strict: process.env.DEBUGGING
  });
```

so far this working but when I write anything to the form the store is always empty
[image]

Am I missing anything else?
I am also open to any new ideas/packages to handle state automatically

I've been using reduxForm previously on react projects
I want something similar to this

Comment: `import { formulateModule } from "vue-formulate";`, "vue-formulate"  is version 1, make sure you you follow the V2 docs [here](https://vueformulate.com/).
Also, It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @ShayaUlman is right — Version 1 is not currently supported anymore. It looks like there is a mixture of `vue-formulate` and `@braid/vue-formulate` going on here.